# Store a user's score in Windows 10 UWP app?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm making an educational game (Windows 10 UWP, C# + XAML) and I need to store user information (in particular, their current score) and retrieve it when they start the app again. I've found a way to do this (see code below) but I have no idea if this is a normal solution to this problem. I'm currently creating a txt file and storing and retrieving data in/from it. Are there more common, or simpler ways to do this?

Here's what I'm currently doing:

**Create the file:**

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("nameOfTextFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists); //other options are ReplaceExisting
```

**Open the file:**

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("nameOfTextFile.txt");
```

**Write text to the file:**

```
  await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, "Put the added text here");
```

**Read text from the file:**

```
string someVariableName = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
```

-Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: This is the correct way to store/read app data for your UWP app. If you don't already, I would suggest storing your settings in an XML file using the same way as above

Comment: Thanks, Geoff! I have been using txt files but only because I didn't know my other options. Do you mind filling me in on some of the advantages of using XML instead?

Comment: As @CheckItOut has suggested, create a class where you can do the `get`ting and `set`ting of your app settings, which will then read/write to the file that way. If you set the attribute of [XmlSerialize] above each property, you can use an XmlSerializer to then write your XML file. Likewise for reverse (loading from XML) I can post an example as an answer if you need

Comment: I'd love to see an example! Thanks for your help, Geoff (and CheckItOut)!

Comment: No probs! Bare with me and I'll see what I can rustle up (unless @CheckItOut can update their answer - I'll upvote if so)

Comment: In the meantime here's some reading material for you on UWP App Settings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data

Answer (score 2):

While the file-based approach is valid, there are easier ways, at least for simple data: You can use roaming (or local) settings. Roaming settings are roamed between devices, as long as their size don't exceed 64K, and would carry the score from the user's desktop to the user's phone, for example. Local settings stay on the machine.

Settings are easy to use:

```
IPropertySet propertySet = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values;

// Get previous score (or 0 if none)
int score = (int)(propertySet["Score"] ?? 0);

// ...play game...

// Set updated score:
propertySet["Score"] = score;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I go about doing projects and settings like this is creating a propery setting in Visual Studio, then Setting and Getting the setting / Value.

You can access this by going to the application properties.
This allows access to read,write, and save information / onload restore information.

Some Informational Links:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx

and (Suggested)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here goes an example of using a class to store your settings in.

There are many, many more ways you could do this. Too many to list.

**Create a settings class**:

```
public class YourSettingsClass
{
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    public string UserScore { get; set; }
}
```

**Create an AppSettings helper**

```
public AppSettings
{
    private static YourSettingsClass _settings = new YourSettingsClass();

    public static string UserFirstName
    {
        get { return _settings.UserFirstName; }
        set { _settings.UserFirstName = value; }
    }

    public static string UserLastName
    {
        get { return _settings.UserLastName; }
        set { _settings.UserLastName = value; }
    }

    public static string UserScore
    {
        get { return _settings.UserScore; }
        set { _settings.UserScore = value; }
    }

    public static void SaveSettings()
    {
        // Now, use your "settingsfile.xml" (or whatever you're saving as)
        // to write your settings to from your _settings static field object.

        // I'll let you have a play as to how you want to do this...
    }

    public static void LoadSettings()
    {
        YourSettingsClass tempSettingsClass = new YourSettingsClass();

        // Now, use your "settingsfile.xml" (or whatever you've saved it as)
        // to load in your settings and assign to your tempSettingsClass variable.

        // I'll let you have a play as to how you want to do this...

        // Assign the settings from your loaded object.
        _settings = tempSettingsClass;
    }
}
```

Now, from any other class, you can call `AppSettings.LoadSettings()`. You could do this on App Startup, or on-demand.

When you've loaded the settings in, just reference `AppSettings.UserFirstName` or whatever property you want to either `get` the value or `set` the value.

When you're ready to, you can then save the settings back to the XML file on disk, through `AppSettings.SaveSettings()`.

I've purposely omitted the code for loading and saving from the storage, and for se/deserializing class objects as I haven't got any UWP components on this PC and I've done this all from memory so I don't want to put anything in to throw you off.

Plus it's a little more learning (even trial/error) for you to do.

**Lastly**

In the `get`ters for your `AppSettings` static properties you could also do a `null` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` check for the `_settings`' property in question, and call the `LoadSettings()` method if so.

This would save you having to manually call it in-code elsewhere.

**Useful links**

[XmlSerializer and how to use the Serialize method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/10y9yyta(v=vs.110).aspx)

[All about what you can do with the FileIO.WriteTextAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701508.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Not an article, but a similar question: [UWP C# Read & Write XML File](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/904a66a5-05d7-4ef1-8d07-d36d81f00f61/uwpc-read-and-write-xml-file?forum=wpdevelop)

I really hope this helps, somewhat.

Good luck!

Comment: This is excellent! Thanks so much for the example and links to other articles, Geoff! I don't personally know any skilled programmers so I really appreciate the helping hand!!

Comment: Glad to be of help :) let me know if there's anything you need - if you've used this in your situation, don't forget to mark as answer :)